# need to create a helper for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create some type of helper for a form where it will create a select for each day of the week.

Below, creates the 5 instances, but only submits the last one.

```
def basic_question(q)
   a = ""
   5.times do 
     a << select("question[question_id_#{q.id}]", :response, (0..30).to_a) + " for #{q.survey.publish_on.strftime('%A')} #{q.survey.publish_on.strftime('%D')} <br />"
   end
   return a.html_safe
end
```

### EDIT

Here is the view to take the survey

```
<%= form_for store_survey_path(@survey) do |f| %>
<% hidden_field.user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

<% @survey.questions.each do |q| %>

  <li><%= q.content %></li>
  <%= question_helper(q) %>

<% end %>
<p><%= f.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

And the helper that checks for the type of question it is.

```
def question_helper(question)
    case question.question_type
    when 'basic'
      return basic_question(question)
    when 'fill_in'
      return fill_in_question(question)
    when 'scale_5'
      return "should return a scale of 5"
    when 'scale_10'
      return "should return a scale of 10"
    when 'must_choose_answer'
      return question.answers.to_s
    when 'just_label'
      return " I will be a label"
    else
      return "Couldn't find in helper"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either go with giving the separate selects different names so that they are submitted separately, or you could submit them all as an array. I would go with the last option.

To submit them as an array, you have to add `[]` to the end of the select name like this:

```
question[question_id_#{q.id}][]
```

Which would end up looking like this:

```
a << select("question[question_id_#{q.id}][]", :response, (0..30).to_a) + " for #{q.survey.publish_on.strftime('%A')} #{q.survey.publish_on.strftime('%D')} <br />"
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Got error. `@question[question_id_2]' is not allowed as an instance variable name.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It would be good if you post your code where you try that bit out. But my guess is that you should access the data with `params[:question]["question_id_#{q.id}".to_sym]`

Comment: got error just posting, not even looping through responses yet.  In the controller all I have is `puts "---- Responses received -> #{params.to_s}`  Will update question with full code.

Comment: So where is the error occurring? If it is in the controller which it sound like then could you also add that code? And any error messages you get.